# startup script yum install fails with “signature could not be verified for google-cloud-sdk”

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I reran the startup script using following command:
`sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup`

All the `yum install` commands are failing with following error:

```
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: Retrieving key from https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/cloud-sdk-el7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml signature could not be verified for google-cloud-sdk
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: Trying other mirror.
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url:  One of the configured repositories failed (Google Cloud SDK),
```

Any idea how I could fix this while instance provisioning or any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

As stated [in BobCares.com's "Plesk update error on CentOS7 GCP"](https://bobcares.com/blog/plesk-update-error-on-centos-7-gcp/),

> The yum repositories do not usually use GPG keys for repository validation. Instead, it uses https endpoint as a trusted one.

I've tried it, and it solved the error in my case. So, try changing the GPG check:

```
sudo sed -i 's/repo_gpgcheck=1/repo_gpgcheck=0/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/google-cloud-sdk.repo
```

In my case (failure to update Plesk), I had this seeting ("repo_gpgcheck=1") in /etc/yum.repos.d/google-cloud-sdk.repo). So, first, locate where you have this setting set to 1, and change accordingly the instruction above.

Afterwards, run again your script. `sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup`

Hopefully it will now work without errors.

Comment: This is also what [Google's own documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment) shows.

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you add this flag to your YUM commands it should allow you to successfully run your startup script.

example:
"yum install --disablerepo=google-cloud-sdk -y cloud-init"